# Definition of short css transition commands?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I found the following short definition of CSS transition commands, but I don't know what those stand for:

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out 0s;
```

What does the `all` stand for?
Why `0s` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `all` means that all [**animatable properties**](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-css3-transitions-20131119/#animatable-properties) are going to be animated; it's the default, so it can be omitted; of course, you are going to see a transition only for those properties that actually change value between initial and final state;
- `0s` is the transition delay; can be omitted if it's `0s` (there may be
  issues in some browsers with writing just `0` instead of `0s`)

So that code is actually equivalent to:

```
transition: .35s ease-in-out;
```

Also, the line you've written uses the `-webkit-` prefix which means it's only going to work only in WebKit browsers. However, [*all current versions of desktop browsers that support transitions support them unprefixed*](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions).

Comment: "(there may be issues in some browsers with writing just 0 instead of 0s)" That's because the unit is always required for time values. Unitless zero values are only permitted for lengths.

Answer (score 1):

1. 'All' specifies the properties to transition.
2. The final time parameter is a delay argument. '0s' means, as you'd expect, no delay.

If I wanted to transition just the background colour, and delay by 4 seconds, I would write:

```
transition: background-color 0.35s ease-in-out 4s;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some great articles detailing the use of `transition` -

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Answer (score 1):

```
transition: <property> <duration> <easing> <delay>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Universal property transition is shorthand for 4 individual properties: `transition-property`, `transition-duration`,`transition-delay`, and `transition-timing-function`.

First 2 properties are required even though a default value for transition-property is all which defines that all properties that can transition will transition. The transition-timing-function property is defined by predefined functions.

Duration and delay properties are defined with seconds or milliseconds, just keep in mind that first time defined is always duration.

Source: https://kolosek.com/css-transition/